# [nginx-config]: replace part of url using 'location'

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

How can I replace part of the URL using location to intercept the URL with the desired part?

here is nginx config part with location describing, but it is not working:

```
location /replace-before {
    rewrite ^.*/replace-before(.*)$ $newPart$1 permanent;
    break;
}
```

where `$newPart = http://google.com`
i have 
    http://localhost:4200/replace-before/data/user?user=name&place=place

and i need to replace 'replace-before' and all in front of it to `$newPart`,
The result should be like this:

```
http://google.com/data/user?user=name&place=place
```

Comment: What do you get with: `curl -I http://localhost:4200/replace-before/data/user?user=name&place=place`?

Comment: it's just for example) i need to replace part of url and save all args

Comment: "Not working" is unhelpful. Using `curl -I` will help you diagnose the reason why it is not working.

Comment: in which moment i need to use it? because i need to catch all url with "/replace-before" part and replace all before that and this part too to $newPart. Maybe it's better to do using another methods without 'location'. But i think, that 'location' can catch all urls with needed part and transform to something else. "Not working" i mean, the url  changes but params is missing, and there is also an appeal to the old url, and then a redirect to the new one (301 moved permanently). It would be nice to have only 1 request instead of 2